# Require wp-load.php returns errors

Tags: php, wordpress, require, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying use wordpress functions outside of wordpress by simply requiring wo-load.php into the header.php of the other website.

Example :

public_html/wp-load.php (main Wordpress directory)
public_html/Other_WebSite_Folder/core/header.php

So inside header.php I have added this code:

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

So theoretically it should work, but what happens is that I am getting this error :

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/public_html/Other_WebSite_Folder/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /public_html/wp-load.php on line 4
```

As you can see, for some reason the require script trying to load wordpress files from the other website folder instead just of loading the functions that i need into it.

I done same sort of integration before and it was working just fine, I can't fiend the reason why this is keep happening right now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

in public_html/Other_WebSite_Folder/core/header.php

```
require_once ('../../wp-load.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me. write full path like below

```
require_once('/home/webroot/website_folder/public_html/wp-load.php');
```